# TradingView drawing future area

Tags: future, point

I'm curious about TradingView.
If a figure is drawn at future coordinates rather than the current point of view, I am curious how to get the corresponding coordinates.

My coordinates are the 359th most up-to-date in the 360 array.
But it's up to date with bars so the future part doesn't work when drawing.
I want to find a way to get future coordinates.
I am using version 1.13

oh sorry I didn't ask in detail.
My question is I want to bring back a part I drew in the past.
However, the drawing line is drawn vertically because the linetool in the chart does not have candle data on the screen yet, so it must be drawn in the nodata zone.
But bybit doesn't. Can you help me?

```
   const widgetOptions = {
        debug: false,
        symbol: this.props.symbol,
        datafeed: Datafeed,
        interval: this.props.interval,
        container_id: this.props.containerId,
        library_path: this.props.libraryPath,
        locale: getLanguageFromURL() || 'en',
        disabled_features: ['use_localstorage_for_settings'],
        enabled_features: ['study_templates'],
        charts_storage_url: this.props.chartsStorageUrl,
        charts_storage_api_version: this.props.chartsStorageApiVersion,
        client_id: this.props.clientId,
        user_id: this.props.userId,
        fullscreen: this.props.fullscreen,
        autosize: this.props.autosize,
        studies_overrides: this.props.studiesOverrides,
        overrides: {
            "mainSeriesProperties.showCountdown": true,
            "paneProperties.background": "#131722",
            "paneProperties.vertGridProperties.color": "#363c4e",
            "paneProperties.horzGridProperties.color": "#363c4e",
            "symbolWatermarkProperties.transparency": 90,
            "scalesProperties.textColor" : "#AAA",
            "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickUpColor": '#336854',
            "mainSeriesProperties.candleStyle.wickDownColor": '#7f323f',
        }
    };

    Datafeed.onReady(() => {
        const widget = (window.tvWidget = new window.TradingView.widget(widgetOptions));

        widget.onChartReady(() => {
            console.log('Chart has loaded!')
        });
    });
```

I need to solve this part, but I still haven't been able to solve it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxlHL.png)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this does not look related to programming to me

Comment: I agree with Nico, but even if it were a programming issue, I would ask to clarify the problem, because I can't make sense of it

Comment: @Nico Haase // um..sorry i'm edited my ask in detail

Comment: @MrCodingB ​// um..sorry i'm edited my ask in detail

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved it
It is to use the response value offset.
The solution was to look at the type of interval through the corresponding offset and add the corresponding time interval.
The best thing is to modify it to be able to draw in a future space, but I'm not sure how to do that.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJ9Kk.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).